# Strange empty space below address bar in Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

[image: strange bar in Microsoft Edge]
Here's the issue in question, with no known cause. The only extension I have installed to Edge is Adblock Plus, from the Windows Store. It appears to be an issue with the browser, as sites are framed below the mysterious bar. Does anybody have any suggestions? (I don't normally use Edge, but webpage testing should be done with all browsers available, so I encountered this.)

Comment: You have a theme going on, my bar is gray, have you tried changing your theme?

Comment: Edge is set to use its dark theme. When I launched Edge again to change it, however, the bar was gone. I don't know if I should just chalk it up to a one-time bug and move on, but I could probably delete this question with no fanfare since it's an ephemeral problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer reproducible.